# Electric field diagrams

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage

[image]

I have these 2 diagrams of an electric field, for the second one i’m not too sure how to draw it because how do i respect the 2 conditions:

1. the field lines need to be perpendicular to the equipotential lines.
2. the equipotential lines are parallel to the surface.
   is there something wrong im doing or misunderstanding?
   Any suggestions as a to how the sketches should look?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know of the principle of mirror charges, it is the easiest way of drawing the pictures.the potential lines are parallel only very close to the boundary. Your picture has alamos no lines perpendicular to the metal?

Comment: Well, should the field lines be perpendicular and then curve?

Comment: Yes, most field lines are curved, maybe look first at the lines between two opposite charges or between to equal charges.